# ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: error when trying to migrate

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, migrate

I am using Django and Python with Anaconda. At the beginning, I was able to migrate by the addition of a sqlite3.dll file. However, when I try to migrate again, it gives me this error. I have tried uninstalling and installing both numpy and pandas in Project Interpreter. I'm using Pycharm and I'm using Conda Package manager with the Conda environment. I also tried migrate --run-syncdb but it still gives me the error.
How would I fix this to be able to use .objects.bulk_create()?
To fix .objects.bulk_create(), one recommendation was to run migrate --run-syncdb and I cannot run it currently because of the error below.

````
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\PuTung\anaconda3\envs\swe_project\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.```
````

Comment: Did you activate your conda environment?